# How to deploy nestjs app to Dreamhost VPS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dreamhost

How do you deploy a nestjs app to Dreamhost VPS?  Simply adding NodeJS and copying up your nestjs dist folder contents to the root of your site does not work.  I can't seem to find any documentation on Dreamhost or nestjs to explain how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to deploy nestjs on Dreamhost

- First make sure NodeJS is setup in your dreamhost panel for your domain as described in the Dreamhost documentation:

  - https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216635318-How-to-enable-Node-js
- Next install the latest version of NVM and then NodeJS. NOTE: MAKE SURE you read the TROUBLESHOOTING section and add the reference to passenger and also there is some info about how to restart node each time you make a change to your app:

  - https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029083351-Installing-a-custom-version-of-NVM-and-Node-js
- In your nestjs app rename main.ts to app.ts (Dreamhost serves app.js by default so you need app.ts in your project src folder)
- In your nestjs app package.json file change any references from main.ts to app.ts
- You need to redirect any requests made to your domain that don't match any files in the public folder and redirect those to your nestjs app running on port 3000. On your Dreamhost VPS site, in the public folder in your domain's root add the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
```

- On your nestjs app's terminal window Run `npm run build`
- Copy up all the files in your nestjs app's dist folder to the root of your dreamhost site, NOT the public folder
- Copy up the package.json file to the root, NOT the public folder
- Run `npm install` in the root of your site on Dreamhost
- You might need to `touch ./tmp/restart.txt` to restart your NodeJS app. In the root of your Dreamhost site, Not the public folder.
- Your site should be working along with your controllers as long as you don't name a controller with the same name as a folder in your public folder.  In your app.ts you might want to set all requests to start with the path /api by setting this: `app.setGlobalPrefix('api');`

Here's a site that I found that helped with figuring out the rewriting that needs to get done to redirect requests to nestjs running on port 3000:
- https://medium.com/@mayomi1/how-to-host-a-node-js-app-on-shared-host-52e12a62a259

Hope that helps anyone else that might try to do this.